# How to riffle a matrix into another matrix

Tags: r, data-structures, matrix

There is a function in Mathematica called "[Riffle](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Riffle.html)" that can be used for inserting columns of a matrix between columns of another matrix.For example, for `m1` and `m2` matrices like these:

```
m1= 1   1   1
    1   1   1
    1   1   1

m2=2    2   2
   2    2   2
   2    2   2
```

it creates

```
1   2   1   2   1   2
1   2   1   2   1   2
1   2   1   2   1   2
```

is there any equivalent function in R for doing this?

Comment: Are you looking for the specific behavior you describe in this question, or something that behaves more like the actual `Riffle` function? If it's the former, something as straightforward as `cbind(m1, m2)[, order(sequence(c(ncol(m1), ncol(m2))))]` should work.

Comment: Something to play around with: https://gist.github.com/mrdwab/8618900

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that you matrices have equal dimensions, you might use this little trick

```
m <- rbind(m1, m2)
dim(m) <- rev(dim(m))

m
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
[1,]    1    2    1    2    1    2
[2,]    1    2    1    2    1    2
[3,]    1    2    1    2    1    2
```

Another option would be to use the `interleave` function from the `gdata` package. The function interleaves rows not columns, so you need to transpose your matrices back and forth.

```
m <- t(interleave(t(m1), t(m2)))

m
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
[1,]    1    2    1    2    1    2
[2,]    1    2    1    2    1    2
[3,]    1    2    1    2    1    2
```

Answer (score 3):

Don't know if it already exists (never seen it), but it is not to difficult to write:

```
riffle <- function(a,b) {
  if (!all(dim(a) == dim(b))) stop("dimensions do not match")
  array(rbind(a, b), dim=c(dim(a)[1], dim(a)[1]+dim(b)[1]))
}
```